# OmniFaces:SelectItemsConverter not working with PrimeFaces: PickList

Tags: jsf, primefaces, omnifaces

I'm trying to use SelectItemsConverter with PrimeFaces Picklist.

XHTML:

```
<p:pickList id="plUpdateFirma" value="#{bsvttController.dlmFirma}" var="plFirma"
    itemLabel="#{plFirma.schluesselFirma}" itemValue="#{plFirma}"
    converter="FirmaConverter">

    <f:facet name="sourceCaption">
        Vorjahr
    </f:facet>
    <f:facet name="targetCaption">
        #{bsvttController.selSaison}
    </f:facet>

    <p:column>
        #{plFirma.schluesselFirma}  
    </p:column>

</p:pickList>
```

Converter:

```
@FacesConverter(value = "FirmaConverter")
public class FirmaConverter extends SelectItemsConverter
{ 

    @Override
    public String getAsString(final FacesContext facesContext, final UIComponent component, final Object object)
    {
        return ((Firma) object).getSchluesselFirma();
    }

}
```

Bean:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class BsvttController implements Serializable
{
    private DualListModel<Firma> dlmFirma;
    private List<Firma> dlmFirmaSource;
    private List<Firma> dlmFirmaTarget;
    private Firma firma;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init()
    {
        dlmFirmaSource = FirmaPersistenz.leseFirmaAlle();
        dlmFirmaTarget = new ArrayList<Firma>();
        dlmFirma = new DualListModel<>(dlmFirmaSource, dlmFirmaTarget);
    }

    public DualListModel<Firma> getDlmFirma()
    {
        return dlmFirma;
    }
    public List<Firma> getDlmFirmaSource()
    {
        return dlmFirmaSource;
    }
    public List<Firma> getDlmFirmaTarget()
    {
        return dlmFirmaTarget;
    }

    public void setDlmFirma(DualListModel<Firma> dlmFirma)
    {
        this.dlmFirma = dlmFirma;
    }
    public void setDlmFirmaSource(List<Firma> dlmFirmaSource)
    {
        this.dlmFirmaSource = dlmFirmaSource;
    }
    public void setDlmFirmaTarget(List<Firma> dlmFirmaTarget)
    {
        this.dlmFirmaTarget = dlmFirmaTarget;
    }

}
```

While debugging converter I could see that getAsString method is working fine. But after submitting the form both arraylists (dlmFirmaSource and dlmFirmaTarget) are empty.

OmniFaces showcase says that

> "The omnifaces.SelectItemsConverter allows you to populate e.g. a drop-down with complex Java model objects as value of f:selectItems and have JSF convert those automatically back without the need to provide a custom converter which may need to do the job based on possibly expensive service/DAO operations."

But in case of PickList component there doesn't exist any f:selectItems tag.

Does SelectItemsConverter even support PickList component?

Answer (score 4):

> *Does SelectItemsConverter even support PickList component?*

No, it doesn't.

Since OmniFaces 1.5, you can use `omnifaces.ListConverter` or `omnifaces.ListIndexConverter` for the desired purpose. See also [the `ListConverter` showcase example](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/converters/ListConverter) which also demonstrates the usage on `<p:pickList>`.

Comment: I am using Omnifaces 1.8.1   and added this converter <o:converter converterId="omnifaces.ListConverter" list="#{selectListBean.source}" 
/>  inside the picklist tags but the "list" attribute is not found
can you please advice ?

Comment: @Samy: It's a dynamic attribute. Just specify it. If the IDE is jerking, ignore it.

Answer (score 2):

No, the SelectItemsConverter handles conversion of core JSF SelectItem objects for use with various JSF components.

The class `DualListModel` is a PrimeFaces specific class meant for use with advanced PrimeFaces data components.  The workaround of course is to possible use a `@PostConstruct` method to initialize your DualListModel in the managed bean so that it does not require a converter, or you can simply implement the converter in the traditional way.  From the PrimeFaces guide on the `converter` attribute of Pick List:

> An el expression or a literal text that defines a
>   converter for the component. When it’s an EL
>   expression, it’s resolved to a converter instance.
>   In case it’s a static text, it must refer to a
>   converter id

Comment: Just in case you're seeking for confirmation, yes maple_shaft is right. The `<p:pickList>` doesn't use `UISelectItem(s)`, so it's end of story. If you really need to, consider a custom converter which injects the bean holding the model.